# Zsh Hook Function Definitions as arguments

Tags: shell, zsh, hook

I would like to know if it's possible to define hook functions as arguments or env var when launching zsh instead of defining it in .zshrc or prompt.

For example ;

```
zsh -F preexec() { date } -F chpwd() { pwd }
```

Thanks alot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not easily unless you add supporting code in your `~/.zshrc`, like:

```
if [[ -o interactive && $1 = eval ]]; then
   "$@"; argv=()
fi
```

And then invoke `zsh` as:

```
zsh -s eval 'preexec() date; chpwd() pwd'
```

for instance.

Same with env vars:

```
if (($+ZSH_STARTUP_CODE)); then
  eval " $ZSH_STARTUP_CODE"
fi
```

And invoke `zsh` as:

```
ZSH_STARTUP_CODE='preexec() date; chpwd() pwd' zsh
```

but note that env variables are inherited, so it would affect all zsh instances started in that environment, and having data from the environment executed automatically makes me generally nervous.